# Issue while compiling in X64 with SFML in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit, sfml

When I try compiling my project in X64 I always have the same error :

```
    LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86
```

I've already test all the solutions I found but i can't figure it out
my VC++ directory is fine :

```
    $(VCInstallDir)lib\amd64;$(VCInstallDir)atlmf\lib\amd64;$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x64);
```

I've properly link the 64 bits version of the SFML in the C/C++ menu and in the linker...

Do you guys know why it's still throwing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project property page, in "Linker -> Advanced", switch "Target Machine" to "MachineX64 "